# How to fix a javascript async fn wrapping a .then callback function that skips to bottom return value?, using 'react-native-permissions' as well

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, callback, permissions

My async function look like

```
import { PERMISSIONS, RESULTS, checkMultiple } from 'react-native-permissions';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
  const checkPermissions = async (): boolean => {
    console.log('Platform.OS', Platform.OS)
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      checkMultiple([
        PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS,
        PERMISSIONS.IOS.MOTION,
      ]).then((status) => {
        if (
          status[PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS] === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
          status[PERMISSIONS.IOS.MOTION] === RESULTS.GRANTED
        ) {
          console.log('permissions allgood');
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log('PERMISSIONS are false.');
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      checkMultiple([
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
      ]).then((status) => {
        if (
          String(status[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION]) ===
            RESULTS.GRANTED &&
          String(status[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION]) ===
            RESULTS.GRANTED
        ) {
          console.log('permissions allgood');
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log('PERMISSIONS are false.');
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
    return 'why';
  };

    const permissionsOn = checkPermissions();
    console.log('permissionsOn',permissionsOn)
```

The results are:
LOG  Platform.OS ios
LOG  permissionsAreON before {"_h": 0, "_i": 1, "_j": "why", "_k": null}//'why'
LOG  permissions allgood

so how do you format an async function wrapping fn.then() and return the result?

Comment: since `checkPermissions = async` why are you using `.then` in the first place and not `await` - also note, an async function always returns a `Promise`

Comment: Please, please, don't mix `async` and `await` with `.then()` code if you can possibly avoid it (and you almost always can).

Comment: a simple fix ... `return checkMultiple([